# Firebase Functions - push notification when new document is created

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following Firestore DB structure:

```
users
  $USER_ID
     notifications
       $DOC1
       $DOC2
       $DOC3
```

I want to push a new notification when a document is created at the user notification collection.

It should be something like this, but I don't know of any way to this for each $UID:

```
exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('users/$UID/notifications')
  .onCreate(async event => {
```

How can I use Firebase Functions to do this? If there is no way, any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I don't know of any way to this for each $UID"?

Comment: $UID is dynamic, it can be any user. I don't really have this info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the following code to trigger your Cloud Function:

```js
    exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore
        .document('users/{userId}/notifications/{docId}')
        .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    
          //You get the values of the newly created doc as follows:
          const newValue = snap.data();
          console.log(newValue);
    
          //You get the parameters as follows:
          const userId = context.params.userId;
          //console.log(userId);
    
          const docId = context.params.docId;
          //console.log(docId);
    
          // You perform here the notification sending
        });
```

For the code for the notification sending, have a look at this official Firebase Cloud Function sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Comment: I dont have any `userId` or `documentId`, the push should work when a new document is created for any user..

Comment: This is exactly what this Cloud Function trigger does. If you create a new document in the sub-collection `notifications` of any `user` document (with a dynamic `userId` value), the Cloud Function will be triggered. You then have to write the code for sending the notification. I hope this clarifies the things.

Comment: Does the cloud function translates `userId` to any userId in this collection?

Comment: When the Cloud Function is triggered, within the `onCreate()` method, you will be able to get the value of the `userId` of the `notifications` collection parent user document. I shown how to do that in my answer (i.e. `const userId = context.params.userId;`). I would suggest you just give a try with the code I've provided: Create and deploy your cloud function, then create a user document, then a `notifications` sub-collection and then a notification doc and look what is printed in the Cloud Functions log in the Firebase console (you should un-comment the `console.log()` of course!)

Comment: Hey Renaud, please can you give me a briefly explain how to show a local notification when there is a new document on a collection? I'm trying it on Ionic 4 but crash a lot... thank you